# What does Conan O'Brien say at 1:28 in this clip of the Conan show

Tags: listening

At 1:28 in [this clip](https://youtu.be/7sdvxEuQkH8?t=87) of the [*Conan* show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_(talk_show)), Conan O'Brien says something I can't understand. I believe listening comprehension is a crucial part of learning the English language, but I'm just not picking up what's said there.

What does Conan O'Brien say at that time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a general transcription, rather than an explanation of something about an attempted transcription, specific ways to transcribe better, or anything else that other learners can search for.

Comment: @NathanTuggy While I'm split on if such questions *should be* off-topic (mostly because it's unclear to me that it will be helpful to future visitors, particularly because it requires an off-site resource to be complete), the [on-topic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page says that a question which is about any "other practical problems you encounter or face while learning English" is on-topic and neither that page, nor the [don't ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page exclude questions such as this one. Thus, IMO, it's *currently* on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

At that time Conan O'Brien says:

> Little shout-out to Justin: How's Satan? … Yeah. That's great.

A "shout-out" is normally a "[a message of congratulation, support, or appreciation.](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20shout-out)" Conan's statement is humorous because it is a [backhanded](https://www.google.com/search?q=backhanded) way of implying that Justin knows Satan well enough to be able to say how Satan is doing (i.e. that Justin is in league with, or has a deal with, Satan).

Comment: In this case, the connection is: Conan's guest is singer-songwriter Bo Burnham. The music video for Burnham's satirical song ["Repeat Stuff"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nt9c0UeYhFc) features Burnham as a Justin Bieber parody who participates in Satanic rituals designed to get little girls to buy his records.